# How is HTTP ChunkSize chosen?

Tags: sockets, http, curl

I've been tinkering in C to handle PUT requests that use [Chunked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding#Chunked_encoding) Encoding, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2127723/9488865) has been immensely helpful.

While handling incoming datastreams, I noticed `curl` seems to use `16372` as the max Chunklen,

```
--> ChunkSize string: 3ff4 Dec: 16372
--> ChunkSize string: 3ff4 Dec: 16372
--> ChunkSize string: 1e7d Dec: 7805
--> ChunkSize string: 0 Dec: 0
```

and Golang seems to use `32768` as max:

```
--> ChunkSize string: 8000 Dec: 32768
--> ChunkSize string: 8000 Dec: 32768
--> ChunkSize string: 1e1d Dec: 7709
--> ChunkSize string: 0 Dec: 0
```

How are ChunkLens chosen by say, curl? Is there a rhyme or reason to choose `16372`, *which btw is not divisible by 8:*

```
>>> 16372 / 8
2046.5
```

When sending a large file, why shouldn't we use a larger chunksize? Anything else I should be aware of when it comes to chunksize?

thanks!

Comment: "is not divisible by 8" --- what is so special in "8 bytes"?

Comment: just an artifact that my char array sizes are multiples of 8.

Comment: It is chosen ny way the sender likes. There is no restriction.

Comment: when curl uploads using chunked encoding, it uses up to its entire upload buffer size for this purpose. That is 16K by default.

Comment: @DanielStenberg, thank you. I see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_UPLOAD_BUFFERSIZE.html now!